# Do I need to connect all pins of USB 4085 or can I use only the first row?

Tags: pcb-design, differential, usb-c

I would like to add a THT USB-C for hand soldering to my PCB. I found this on KiCad:
https://gct.co/connector/usb4085

[image]
(Full schematics)

D+ and D- are differential pairs.

Do I need to connect all of them or can I use only the first row?

If I have to connect them all, how can I place the traces? one on each layer?
[image]

Comment: If you don't connect both then the usb-c becomes a usb A and you will never get it to plug in the right way on the first 2 trys /s

Comment: Just a note to check with your fabricator and make sure they can create elongated plated-through-holes.  Some cannot.

Comment: Thanks @rdtsc! I usually use JLCPCB. Do you know if they support that?

Comment: @Passerby. Do you mean that the USB will only work if I plug the wire in one specific way?

Comment: @carlos yes. If you don't connect both pairs then the function of any way plugging in won't work in situations where the wire and or other end also lacks both connections.

Comment: @Passerby and how should i connect them in my PCB? I have been reading a lot about impedance and noise in those wires, and they seem to be very sensitive, Can I simply route each of them in a different layer? (it's a 2 layers board)

Comment: @carlos see my answer. Also reach out to the manufacturer support for recommended layout or demo board files maybe.

Comment: Note that you also need a 5.1K resistor on the CC1 pin to ground, and another 5.1k resistor on the CC2 to ground, else it won't work with the majority of the other devices

Comment: Thank you Ferrybig!! I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a USB C receptacle should but is not required to, have both D+ and D- connected. A USB C plug may but may not have both D+ and D- pairs present. If not, you will get in a situation where plugging in a cable could not work data wise. This is an inconvenience and breaks the normal user expectations of reversible cables. Worse if both sides of the connection do this. See https://hackaday.com/2021/03/22/cursed-usb-c-when-plug-orientation-matters/ for an example and page 11 and 12 of this texas instrument primer https://www.ti.com/lit/slyy109

USB data connections are high speed and should be impedance matched. That typically means the total length of each connection should be equal. There is some leeway but best practices is to make sure it's equal length. Connecting one side above and the other below should not be an issue, the difference being at worst the height of your board. USB 2.0 has some forgiving specs. See the layout of this TI expert recommendation https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/512449/type-c-connector-layout-made-easy

But the best source will probably be your usb c receptacle manufacturer. They likely have an app note or demo board that documents a recommended layout.

Comment: Standard USB-C plugs have only one D+/D- pair connectors. Only a special Audio Accessory plugs have both D+/- sides used in analog mode.